# Visual Studio - move cursor to out of closing brace keyboard shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Given the following code example

```
someMethod(②someArgument①);③
```

I know moving the cursor from position **①->②** shortcut is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>, is there a **①->③** shortcut.

Is there a keyboard shortcut that escapes the brace when cursor is just left of brace (Not with <kbd>End</kbd> key).

In Eclipse, It can easily work with <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

(In Visual Studio) - Try `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`]` - That seems to select text to where you might need to be, but if you press the `]` again, by itself, it deselects, but leaves the cursor where you appear to want it.

Is that what you're looking for?